# get a character at a given position in a linux console application

Tags: c++, linux, terminal, console-application

In the following program I'm trying to improve the function `GetCharAt` which returns a character at a given position and `SetCursorPosition` which moves the terminal cursor to a given position, in a **linux** C++ console application. But each function interferes with the other. for example in `main`, commenting out `SetCursorPosition` will bring back normal functionality of `GetCharAt`.

```
#include <streambuf>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include <stdio.h>

string console_string;

struct capturebuf : public streambuf
{
    streambuf* d_sbuf;

public:
    capturebuf():
        d_sbuf(cout.rdbuf())

    {
        cout.rdbuf(this);
    }
    ~capturebuf()
    {
        cout.rdbuf(this -> d_sbuf);
    }
    int overflow(int c)
    {
        if (c != char_traits<char>::eof())
        {
            console_string.push_back(c);
        }
        return this -> d_sbuf->sputc(c);
    }
    int sync()
    {
        return this -> d_sbuf->pubsync();
    }
} console_string_activator;

char GetCharAt(short x, short y)
{
    if(x < 1)
        x = 1;
    if(y < 1)
        y = 1;

    bool falg = false;
    unsigned i;
    for(i = 0; 1 < y; i++)
    {
        if(i >=  console_string.size())
            return 0;
        if(console_string[i] == '\n')
            y--;
    }
    unsigned j;
    for(j = 0; console_string[i + j] != '\n' && j < x; j++)
    {
        if(i + j >= console_string.size())
            return 0;
    }
    if(i + j - 1 < console_string.size())
        return console_string[i + j - 1];
    return 0;
}

void SetCursorPosition(short x,short y)
{
    char buffer1[33] = {0};
    char buffer2[33] = {0};

    string a = "\e[";

    sprintf(buffer1,"%i",y);
    sprintf(buffer2,"%i",x);

    string xx = buffer1;
    string yy = buffer2;

    cout<< a + xx + ";" + yy + "f";
    cout.flush();
}

void SetCursorPosition2(short x, short y)
{
    printf("\e[%i;%if",x,y);
    cout.flush();
}

int main()
{
    SetCursorPosition(1,1); // comment out this line for normal functionality
    cout << "hello" "\n";

    for(unsigned j = 1; j <= 5; j++)
    {
        printf("%c",GetCharAt(j,1));
    }
    cout<< "\n";
}
```

How can I change `SetCursorPosition` so that it does not interfere with `GetCharAt`?

Answer (score 1):

The approach you're trying here is so fragile as to be impossible.  `GetCharAt()` assumes that every character that's output is printable, and that nothing is moving the cursor around.  Your `SetCursorPosition()` does exactly that, so the idea of tracking what has been output so far simply will not work.

Plus, other processes may output stuff to the console right in the middle of your program, like a `wall` message from root.  What you want instead is "ncurses", http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ncurses, a library that probably already exists on your system.  It has solved these problems already in a terminal-independent way, and provides a large suite of functions for moving around the screen, scrolling, drawing, colors, etc, all in the terminal.

Comment: ncurses is not open source. I'm looking for a general terminal solution. There must be some method to access contents of a terminal like konsole, xterm or gnome.

Comment: Of course it's open source: http://www.gnu.org/software/ncurses/.  It *is* the general terminal solution.

Comment: in [this page](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/ncurses.faq.html#who_claims_it) it is said it is not open source. btw, I'll be glad if my program is improved or if I can copy all contents of terminal stdout.

Comment: OK, fine, it's "free software", not "open source".  In this case, "free software" is even more liberal than "open source".  Basically, you can do whatever you want with the software, as long as you retain the copyright notice.  Really, based on what you've said so far, you want to use this library.